# docker in mac: ./start.sh: no such file or directory"

Tags: macos, docker, macos-sierra

I am trying to run docker on my macbook with sierra... It is okay to build and run on my openshift but I have a problem on local. I think the problem is in this line:
COPY . /tmp/app

and the docker cant copy files (including start.sh) to path. can you help me please?

[image: dockerfile]

Comment: There is a conflict between lines 83 and 98. Either set the working directory to that of 83 or add the full path on 98.

Comment: Add the code, not the pic.